# Redirecting of HTTP request on Vite-Vue app - DEV mode

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I want to change base URL of HTTP requests from host adress of Vite app ( http://localhost:5173) to host adress of my ASP .NET API (http://localhost:5815) on dev mode (npm run dev).

[image]

But I have such error during run of my Vite-Vue app after apply proxy to redirecting requests:

[image]

My vite.config.js file:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  build: {
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5815',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\//, '')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I also tried such vite.config file

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  build: {
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5815',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Result was that:

[image]

What I should do in order to redirect all of my HTTP requests from
localhost:5173 to localhost:5815 during run my in dev mode (npm run dev)?

I mention only that similar project with only Vue, worked with this vue.config file:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  lintOnSave: false,
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:5815',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case, you need a path different from the root (since from the root, the website's assets such as CSS, JS, and other files are loaded).

```js
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5815',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''), // It removes the /api from the request address, so it will truly be used only for differentiation
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Every address associated with `/api` will be redirected to `localhost:5815`. In the example, you see accessing `localhost:5815/some-endpoint`:

```js
// Before
axios.get('/some-endpoint') // With what you are currently trying, it will never work from the root
// Call http://localhost:5173/some-endpoint (Vite Host)

// After
axios.get('/api/some-endpoint') // With the /api proxy route defined now, it works
// Call http://localhost:5815/some-endpoint (Your Custom API)
```

How can this target proxy address be modified in the live production version? Simply check whether Vite is currently running in dev or prod mode. Accordingly, the address can be dynamically set.

```js
const API_URI = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? 'http://example.com'    // in prod
  : 'http://localhost:5815' // in dev

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: API_URI,
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: I modified my vite.config.js file, but when page requesting for example http://localhost:5173/getarticles, I have 404 response.

Comment: And i forget to tell that in project I not have requests with URL like that:  "[localhost or something else]/api". Example of my request is:  localhost:5173/getarticles, without "api".

Comment: I feel that you want to achieve the impossible. You want to say that the requests coming out of your application sometimes need to be loaded from `localhost:5173`, such as the app's index.html, JS files, CSS files, images, fonts, etc., but you also want to fetch your API routes from here in a mixed manner. If rewriting the routes is not feasible, you are in a difficult situation. Because you have to declare each API route individually, such as `/getusers`, `/getposts`, `/getarticles`, etc., and redirect each one to its counterpart on `localhost:5815`.

Comment: I find it more practical to create a common `/api` route under which you will handle these. The /api is just a common group name in your frontend app, as mentioned, it won't be included in the URL thanks to `path.replace()`. So, following my solution, it's your job to add a `/api` prefix before each API route call in your frontend application.

Comment: So when you call the `/api/getarticles` example endpoint, Vite will automatically invoke `http://localhost:5815/getarticles`, thanks to the `/api` proxy. Due to `path.replace()`, as you can see, the `/api` prefix will not be included in the new URL address.

Comment: You don't need to include the domain in the URL address; Vite will handle that for you since you've set up the proxy. In this case, `localhost:5173/api/getarticles` will be redirected to `localhost:5815/getarticles`. 
If this is not suitable for you, then you would have to individually set up a proxy for each address. However, I believe this is not a good solution and is not standard practice. In any case, I recommend consolidating your API routes under the mentioned API (or a name of your choice) group, so you can easily identify that URLs starting with this group name are API queries.

Comment: you explained me this perfectly - I modified according to your advices and it work!